# Longer execution time

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below code is taking excessively long time when executed for larger inputs such as x = 23!!!! and y = 5!!!!!. The output of the code should be comparison between x and y. small example regarding the inputs is, if input is 3!!, this means (3!)!) = 6! = 720.

def large()

```
t = int(input())    
i = 0
fact_str = ""
fact_stry = ""
res, resy = 1, 1    
counter = 0
countery = 0
while(i < t):
    x = input()
    y = input()             
    for char in x:          
        if char == '!' and counter == 0:                
            fact_str = int(fact_str)
            for num in range(fact_str, 0, -1):
                res = res * num
            counter = counter + 1
        elif counter > 0:               
            for num in range(res-1, 0, -1):                 
                res = res * num
        else:
            fact_str = str(fact_str)                                
            fact_str = fact_str + char              
    for chary in y:         
        if chary == '!' and countery == 0:              
            fact_stry = int(fact_stry)
            for numy in range(fact_stry, 0, -1):
                resy = resy * numy
            countery = countery + 1
        elif countery > 0:              
            for num in range(resy-1, 0, -1):                    
                resy = resy * numy
        else:   
            print("at esle", resy)  
            fact_stry = str(fact_stry)      
            fact_stry = fact_stry + chary               
        if len(str(x)) == len(str(fact_str)):
            fact_str = int(fact_str)
            x = fact_str
        else:
            x = res
        if len(str(y)) == len(str(fact_stry)):
            fact_stry = int(fact_stry)
            y = fact_stry
        else:
            y = res
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
    if x == y:
        print("x=y")
    elif x > y:
        print("x>y")
    else:
        print("x<y")
    i = i + 1
```

large()

can this code be optimized so that it can execute faster if inputs are large values ? Or python is limited to smaller inputs ?

Comment: Isn't 23!!!! really really big? Like, "could not be stored in the memory of any physical computer, even if it was made from every atom in the observable universe" big?

Comment: I'll have to agree with Kevin, you have to realize how big anything more than a double factorial would be... like try even thinking about what 23!! would be equal to and then try to conceptualize adding 3 more ! to that sequence...

Comment: Assuming x and y can only ever be a sequence of digits followed by one or more exclamation points, perhaps you could drop "!"s from both sides until one has none. ex. `23 < 5!` implies `23!!!! < 5!!!!!`

Comment: Besides whether any numbers are too big, I'm not even sure this code works for small inputs. (For example, the `y = res` line looks suspicious.) At the very least, you need to post your *actual* code, so we can try to reproduce your results.

Comment: I made a very simple algorithm that can solve `23!!!! < 5!!!!!` in very little time. The key is to cancel the unnecessary factorials; then gradually count the remaining products in the one that has more `!`s, and compare them with the constant one; if the product so far is greater than the constant expression, one can exit the loop.

Comment: Also, `23!!` alone would require in the order of million exabytes of storage, I am pretty sure you do not have enough RAM for that.

Comment: Haha - If you type "23factorial" into google, it gives you "2.5852017e+22" and if you type "2.5852017e+22 factorial" into google, the top page is [How to prevent overflow](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1694845) ...

Comment: @Kevin, R Nar, Antti, Dwanderson -Thanks guys !!  I too thought of the same when I got an input as such. However, I got a similar input while I was appearing for a coding challenge and my code did not respond for that and gave memory error. I do not know, why they have provided such an input. But the code had to run on an online compiler/editor. So, I had a doubt if in that case also my system memory was used.?

Comment: @Antti - Thanks Antti, Your approach seems to be a very good one. I would definitely try it out.